# How to add a special repository to the sonatype nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I am new in Maven. So be calm ;)

In my company we are using a Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager.

Now I have found two big repositories which contain the special artifact (JCraft - Jsch) I was searching for:

- http://search.maven.org/ (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.53)
- http://mvnrepository.com/ (http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22com.jcraft%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jsch%22)

Now, I want to know how to add one (or both) of the repositories above to my maven repositories. For this I need several things like a "Remote Storage Location" (an URL) of the repository I want to add. But I can't find it anywhere on the pages above.

Can you help me?!

Comment: Why are you using a SNAPSHOT version of the professional edition? BTW: Maven Central is already in you configuration `Central`...

Answer (score 0):

Both artifacts you are looking for are already available in a default installation of the Nexus Repository Manager.

This is due to the fact that they are available in the Central Repository and it is configured as a proxy repository and part of the public repository group.

Please read more about the configuration for Maven and the repository manager in general in the documentation.

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config.html